# The if block in the onCreateView isn't executing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am building an app that has multiple fragments and about half of those fragments contain a view that a user can draw lines with a finger (we'll call canvas). What I'm trying to do is to save the lines drawn by the user who then leaves the fragment for another one and draws some lines on the canvas in that fragment and can go back to the previous fragment (the drawing of the second will get saved) where the drawing for that fragment only will show in the canvas. If the user goes back to the second fragment, the drawing for the second fragment only will show. I am using the Parcelable interface.

However, if a drawing is made on one canvas in one fragment, the drawing will also be seen in the other fragment and any new additions will be seen in the first canvas.

After using multiple Log.d, I noticed that it isn't going into an if statement that check if savedInstanceState isn't null.

**Fragment one**

*each fragment is essentially the same code just getting a different canvas id*

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class LineLHwFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_l_hw, container, false);
        paintView = v.findViewById(R.id.lineLPaintView);

        // this if code is not getting executed, the logcat will show: first if line fail: 
        //onCreateView: first if line fail 
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d("first line if success", "onCreateView: first line if success");
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("line test")) {
                Log.d("line if working", "onCreateView: line if working");
                paintView.setPaths(savedInstanceState.<FingerPath>getParcelableArrayList("line test"));

            } else {
                Log.d("line fail", "onCreateView: line fail");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("first if line fail", "onCreateView: first if line fail");
        }


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("line test", paintView.getPaths());
}


}
```

I have tried using other ways such as: if (! savedInstanceState.isEmpty()) but that just caused the app to crash. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: do you use `savedInstanceState` to get previous fragment data when you switch between fragments and come back to the particaular fragment that you saved data on its `savedInstanceState`  ?

Comment: I believe I am checking if 'savedInstanceState' is not null in 'onCreateView' and then check for the key that has the appropriate arraylist (that was saved in 'onSaveInstanceState' which I think I've done correctly) and supply that data to paintView.

Comment: I mean if the `onCreateView` is called when you came from another fragment, defintely `savedInstanceState` will be null, I just need to know when do you expect  `onCreateView`

Comment: if I went to the fragment the first time, `savedInstanceState` should be null but when I go back it should not be null and the drawing from the first fragment should only stay in the relevant fragment